# Does MYSQL join before LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, database-design

Imagine that I want to populate the last 10 questions of stackoverflow. I have a table that keep the questions list, a table to keep the question info, a table to list question's asker.

Now imagine that I want to get the last ten questions, so I have to join some tables and get the last items by `ORDER BY ... DESC LIMIT 0 , 10`. This gets me the last ten questions without any problems, but I think that there may be one issue.

MySQL may be first joining all tables and then pick the last ten items, so if I have to join 1 million rows to 1 million rows, it gets really bad performance.

I want to know if MySQL does do this, and if yes, how can I go around this issue?.

Comment: Why haven't you tried yet?

Comment: if I did it , I did not asked here :D

Comment: If you'd did it, you didn't get a downvote from me.

Comment: But, you'll get an upvote from me. +1 !!! This is actually not a bad question.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA do you consider this a good question?  The latter part is a real problem, but this question clearly shows no sign of research...

Comment: @dezso It's probably more of an debatable, borderline argumentative question. Sometimes refactoring queries works. Other times, it can shoot you in the foot. Perhaps this could have been asked on StackOverflow and get a larger audience of seasoned developers involved (just my opinion). That is why I used one of my old answers from StackOverflow.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I think you answered perfectly (dropped a +1).  My problem is that the normal order of joins and `LIMIT` can be checked very easily.  (Of course, you are right, without knowing the actual query we can't tell whether there is an easy solution or not.)

Comment: @dezso you are right, developers can check. But, in all honestly, I think some are afraid to do something radical with the query (or indexes, table design) if the EXPLAIN is not to their liking. Thus, some people will ask without research.

Comment: @Ata the check is this simple: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/96b0c7/2 There is clearly no sign of user2 or user3 in the output, which means that the `JOIN` is performed first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way around it is to refactor the query so as to alter the order of the EXPLAIN plan.

EXAMPLE : On May 16, 2011, I once answered a very rough question on StackOverflow

## Fetching a Single Row from Join Table

- **Question** : [I had to join tables together and return only the 40 most recent results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5983156/491757).
- **My Answer** : [I proved that you can do a JOIN on tables with large rows and get results fast](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023217/491757).
- **How I did it** : I had applied [principles of refactoring queries I learned from a Youtube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVisY-fEoMw&feature=share&list=PL0194B59719B45A96).

Basically, you have to construct the query so that `JOIN` clauses are done last. Consequently, this implies that you must get the `LIMIT` executed beforehand.

Comment: I also think of using two select like here : SELECT ... JOIN ... JOIN ... ON (SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,10 ) JOIN ... . Is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/limit-optimization.html

> If you use LIMIT row_count with ORDER BY, MySQL ends the sorting as
>   soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result,
>   rather than sorting the entire result. If ordering is done by using an
>   index, this is very fast. If a filesort must be done, all rows that
>   match the query without the LIMIT clause must be selected, and most or
>   all of them must be sorted, before it can be ascertained that the
>   first row_count rows have been found. In either case, after the
>   initial rows have been found, there is no need to sort any remainder
>   of the result set, and MySQL does not do so.

This is also true for queries with a simple `JOIN`.

`EXPLAIN` shows you the affected row count.

Comment: Let me add that in the case of a JOIN, it must be performed first to get the output rows to be sorted.

Comment: The `JOIN` performed first, does not necessarily mean that all the trillion rows will be fetched into memory and then only the 10 transmitted.