# MySQL: Data pagination according data on another table

Tags: mysql, join, pagination

I have a database with the following structure

- Items table: itemID, itemName
- Ads table: AdsId, itemID

I would like to make pagination on items table, 10 items in each page, but first I must retrieve items whose IDs are in the Ads table, and then retrieve other items.

I know I must use `limit` such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Items LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page
```

And may I `join`ed it with adsTable, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM Items inner join Ads on Ads.itemID = Items.itemID
LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page
```

but how can I achieve what I described?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### METHOD #1

You could create a temp table called `itemID_paginator` and paginate this

```
CREATE TABLE items_paginator AS SELECT itemID from Items WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE items_paginator ADD PRIMARY KEY (itemID);
INSERT INTO items_paginator SELECT itemID from Items;
```

You then paginate against `itemID_paginator` and join it to Ads

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM 
(
    SELECT itemID FROM itemID_paginator ORDER BY ItemID
    LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page
) PG
INNER JOIN Items A ON PG.ItemID = A.ItemID
INNER JOIN Ads   B ON A.ItemID  = B.ItemID;
```

### METHOD #2

If you prefer not to use a temp table, then perform `LIMIT` directly to the `Items` table

```
SELECT A.*,B.* FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM Items ORDER BY ItemID
    LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page
) A INNER JOIN Ads B ON A.ItemID  = B.ItemID;
```

I suggested these methods before in the following posts:

- `Jan 31, 2017` : [Slow query while selecting a higher offset from millions of rows](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94188/slow-query-while-selecting-a-higher-offset-from-millions-of-rows/162779#162779)
- `Dec 21, 2013` : [Using OFFSET in a large table by a simple sub-query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55435/using-offset-in-a-large-table-by-a-simple-sub-query/55436#55436)
- `Feb 21, 2013` : [Does MYSQL join before LIMIT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35152/does-mysql-join-before-limit/35153#35153)
- `May 16, 2011` : [Fetching a Single Row from Join Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6023217/491757)

### GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but what I would like to do is to get items whose ids in ads table, when retrieving those items finished then get other items not in ads table.

Comment: If you want to see ItemIDs that do not have ads, change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: If you want all ItemIDs that have no ads after, add `ORDER BY B.ISNULL(B.ItemID)` after the `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use `ORDER BY` when using `LIMIT`.  Else the rows you get will be unpredictable.

Yes, `JOIN` works.  Think of it this way:  A `JOIN` combines tables in a specified way and (logically) creates a new table that contains the combined stuff.  After the `JOIN` is done, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT` are 'performed', *in that order*.

I say, "logically" because the Optimizer has a lot of tricks to make the query more efficient than blindly creating a temp table, then filtering, then (etc).

SQL specifies what you want in a rigorous way.  The Optimizer is free to rearrange things *as long as it gets the same answer*.

`OFFSET` is the obvious way to do pagination.  But it leads to bugs (not in MySQL, but in its application on web sites.)  And performance suffers because the rows skipped are actually stepped over one-by-one.  More:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

Comment: Thanks for your explanation,here (when I asked) forget to write ORDER BY with my query, but that is didn't answer what a want to achieve.